# What 12 volt charger should I get for the Canon S95 battery?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, charger

Can anyone recommend me a 12v/cigarette lighter charger for the Canon S95 please? It is very important that it does not catch fire.

Alternatively, a means to charge from AA batteries?

Comment: LOL - *Most* photography related equipment recommendations are important that the items don't catch fire.

Comment: You mean a charger for the battery, right? Because the camera itself does not charge, though it would be pretty awesome if you could plug it into your computer and charge it like you charged an iPhone.

Comment: @Jason Yep, on the S95 you take the battery out and put it into a charging cradle

Comment: I am so tempted to tag this with `fire`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend going with a decently rated [power inverter](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=power+inverter&x=0&y=0&sprefix=power+inverter): One example would be this ["can sized" version from Rosewill](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YMIUD0).

That way you can use it with the standard charger, plus it's not a single purpose item.

Comment: Good call, I hadn't even thought of that (and I am a mechanical engineer by training!). What do you think of [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Silverline-675258-Watt--Car-Inverter/dp/B000OO9V48/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1297368510&sr=8-2)?

Comment: Seems to me that it'd work just fine.

Comment: Worked for my laptops (not this model, though), so why shouldn't it work for a recharger?